# Сравнение в алгебре по остатку

Tags: математика

как можно решить сравнение по остатку от деления на 29:

> x^3+8x^2+19x+14=0(29)

Comment: на каком языке? Покажите ваши попытки :D

Comment: Не программа, а по алгебре по теме "Целые числа"

Comment: 1. Это равенство; 2. Найти корни квадратного уравнения можно найти с помощью дискриминанта и формулы корней или Теоремы Виета

Comment: Проблема в том что это не равенство,а сравнение по остатку от деления на 29.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

перепишем выражение

```
x^3 + 8x^2 + 19x + 14
```

в виде

```
(x + 2)(x^2 + 6x + 7)
```

при решении уравнения

```
(x + 2)(x^2 + 6x + 7) = 0
```

получается один целочисленный корень:

```
x = -2
```

отсюда решение изначального уравнения:

```
x = -2 mod 29 = 27 mod 29
```

или если переписать в другом виде, то

```
x = 29 * a + 27
```

где `a` - принадлежит множеству целых чисел